# it is possible to connect data lake table and view in power BI using REST API

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql, powerbi-embedded

i have required need to read data lake analytic table in power bi, but it is not possible.

can we do using REST API.

Comment: Can we use C# to connect Data lake analytic database  with power BI

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible. We need interactive capabilities for this scenario. Please upvote the following feature asks that are currently on our radar related to this:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/11266677-support-interactive-workloads-within-adl-analytics

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/15189021-view-tables-in-powerbi

Comment: Thanks for the links. Voted!